# Android MediaPlayer.create failing

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer

So I've been trying some stuff with the MediaPlayer, and it works if I do this:

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.over);
```

However, obviously this only allows me to launch that one file.
So, if I try something like this:

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("R.raw.over");
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, myUri);
```

then the mediaPlayer doesn't get created. Any method call

```
mediaPlayer.start()
```

throws a NullPointerException.

My idea is that, if I get this to work, then eventually I can playback a file from an ArayList containing URIs.

Comment: I checked that link, got it to work! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the files that you want to play is in raw folder then you don't need to parse a Uri you can just store them in an array and play through that array:

```
int[] files = {R.raw.over, R.raw.over1, R.raw.over2}
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, files[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, try to apply this code:

```
Uri myUri = ....; // initialize Uri here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```